# Process REST request to retrieve data via Hibernate in a separate Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, transactions

We have a java, spring, osgi application with a jersey REST interface.

In that setting I need to send data to a mobile device running winCE CF 3.5 so it has only 4 MiB RAM per process. This means even a thousand data objects let the MDEs memory over flow.

To solve the problem the idea is to split the request.

1. initial request to query the data, split it into fragments, encode them as JSON, store them on the HDD and return how many fragments there are, together with a reference
2. followup requests will retrieve one fragment at a time, where the fragment size is just a few 100 KiB

This should work even with a really crappy connection and allow the MDE to request the fragments as slow and as often as it needs to, while still getting the same data snap shot.

My idea for the first request is, to query the data with a hibernate criteria into a scrollable result, scroll to the end, get the total results from the row number this way and create an answer to the intital request, while in the back ground scroll back to the start and process the results into json files on the hard disk.

The whole hibernate stuff should happen in one background thread which notifies the REST-request-thread once to provide data about the results but no actual results data.

Now I already read that Hibernate and Multithreading are a very dangerous mix. Yet it seems to me I can avoid the trouble if everything Hibernate related is happinging in the background thread.

```
@Path("/1/mde/articles/")
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Transactional
public class RestMdeArticleController
{
  private static final Logger              LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestMdeArticleController.class);

  @Context
  private HttpServletRequest               request;
  @Autowired
  private IResultFragmentationController   resultFragmentationController;
  @Autowired
  private IFindMasterDataStrategy          masterDataFinder;
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory                   sessionFactory;

  @Path("fragment")
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public FragmentedResultInfo getAllMdeArticlesFragmentedThreaded()
  {
    final FragmentedResultInfo info = new FragmentedResultInfo();

    Thread worker = new Thread((new Runnable() {
      private FragmentedResultInfo info = null;

      public Runnable setInfo(FragmentedResultInfo info)
      {
        this.info = info;
        return this;
      }

      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        try
        {
          HibernateTemplate template = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory, true);
          template.execute((new HibernateCallback<Object>()
          {
            private FragmentedResultInfo info = null; ;

            public HibernateCallback<Object> setInfo(FragmentedResultInfo info)
            {
              this.info = info;
              return this;
            }

            @Override
            public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
            {
              ScrollableResults results = masterDataFinder.findArticles(null, new ArticleFilterOptions<Article>(), ScrollMode.SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
              resultFragmentationController.createFragments(this.info, results, Article.class, MdeTransferArticle.class);

              return null;
            }

          }).setInfo(info));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          LogUtil.error(LOG, e, "Thread failed with {1}", e.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
        finally
        {
          synchronized (info)
          {
            info.notify();
          }
        }
      }

    }).setInfo(info));

    worker.start();

    synchronized (info)
    {
      try
      {
        // wait for the worker to notify (that it updated the values in info)
        info.wait();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
        LogUtil.warn(LOG, e, "waiting for thread '{0}' failed with InterruptedException", worker.getName());
      }
    }

    return info;
  }
}
```

The problem is I still don't get a Hibernate-session in the new thread.

I would like to know how to get a Hibernate-session in the child thread and if this whole setup has any chance to work at all. Are there any pitfalls I have not yet considered, which I should be aware of?
If you have a better idea how to deal with the over all problem (of splitting the data up) I would be open to that as well.

## EDIT 1:

I get a:

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here; 
>     nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

at this line in the depth of the masterDatafinder:

```
getSessionFactory()
    .getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(getEntityName(entityClass, storageMode))
    .setComment(StringUtil.normalize(comment))
    .setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```

---

It seems to me I left out some vital information. This is for synchronizing master data to a mobile device in offline/batch modus. The mobile device will not have a connection most of the time.

While the data on the mobile device will be out of date/sync most of the time, it should at least be consistently so. Retrieving pages independently would give me data belonging to a different point in time with each request.
Doing a SELECT COUNT(*) before retrieving the actual data may also give me different results if the data changed in the few milliseconds that would take.

I got the idea of the result scrolling from a post that supposedly had it from a Hibernate book. The data is not actually retrieved. Here is the start of the ResultFragmentationController:

```
results.last();
totalResults = results.getRowNumber() + 1;
totalFragments = BigDecimal.valueOf(totalResults).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(fragmentSize), 0, RoundingMode.UP).intValue();

info.setTotalFragments(totalFragments);
info.setTotalResults(totalResults);
info.setFragmentSize(fragmentSize);
info.setStatus(EState.IN_PROGRESS);

synchronized (info)
{
  info.notify();
}

// reset the results pointer to the initial position
results.beforeFirst();

while (results.next())
{
  ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't get a Hibernate-session"? What did you try and what happened. Exceptions? Where?

Comment: Also: don't scroll through a result set just to count the elements. execute a select with a count instead. Don't store the result on the backend, instead execute paginated queries on demand. Do you really need the first request or can you just start with a request like: gimme the first 100 of Whatever and let me know if there are more, would save one roundtrip and probably limit the amount of information needed to stor on the client

Comment: @Jens: thanks for your ideas but I do not think they will give me what I need in this case - see Edit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HibernateTemplate` should allow you to create a new Hibernate `Session` because the current `SpringSessionContext` `ThreadLocal` storage has no Session bound.

Related to the design, you should close the `ScrollableResults` and release the database related resources (connection, cursor).

I would therefore design it like this:

1. The initial request builds a Command that is assigned an UUID and the Command is passed to an ExecutorService to be processed asynchronously. The result of the execution is cached.
2. Any subsequent request uses the same UUID to fetch the computation Result from the Cache. You can use a `Future` so that the client code blocks untile the Computation is over.

The asynchronous block calculating the Result object must always close the Hibernate session and free the database connection resources.

Comment: thanks for the reminder to close the `ScrollableResults`, session and db resources - thats something I still over looked even though its not the current problem

Comment: it seems to me, that what you propose and how I designed it so far, are more or less the same thing - I guess my problem is that I still need to explicitly open a new session some how

Comment: Pretty much yes. But I think you should save results in memory and not on disk.

Comment: Well we have one project (which currently has its own code) where up to 1000000 objects get synced to the MDE. I certainly do not want 1 million data objects in RAM which most likely would not fit any way. Also the data will be send as JSON and the mobile device takes some time to process each request. So its not a (time) problem to read the fragments from disk.

Comment: Makes sense. Probably a key value store like Redis fits nicely then.

Comment: turns out the actual problem had to do with our authentication system - still the answer was somewhat helpful so I accept it